# Accessing variables from another user scope in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scope, su

I'm having trouble with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

myPassword="foobar"

su - postgres <<-'EOF'
    echo $myPassword # nil
EOF

echo $myPassword # foobar
```

How can I access or pipe the contents of `$myPassword` from within the `postgres` user session?

Tried it with and without `export` with not luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `'EOF'` for the heredoc marker. So no substitution happens. Remove the quotes around that if you want variable substitution inside the block. See [Heredocs And Herestrings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput?#Heredocs_And_Herestrings).

You could also keep what you have, but use the `-p` (or `-m` or `--preserve-environment`) option of `su` which might work better for you.

(I'm sure there's no need to remind you that keeping passwords in scripts is unsafe. And a process's environment can be inspected with sufficient privileges, so it's not a great place for passwords either.)

Comment: Thank you, I ended up removing the quotes and it works perfectly. =)

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to escape `\$mypassword` so that it doesn't get resolved in the original script before calling `su`

also, you can pass `-c` to `su` in order to pass something from the environment to the spawned shell:

```
user1:~$ X=foo su -c "bash -c \"whoami && echo \$X\"" user2
Password: 
user2
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This su command should work:

```
myPassword="foobar"
su postgress -c "echo $myPassword"
```